# How to check, throw and catch bean's validation ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, spring, exception, bean-validation

Consider the following case:

- I have a "serivce" module that has a class called `ClientService`.
- This `ClientService` uses a class called `ClientDao` in a "dao" module.
- `ClientDao` has a method `insert(@Valid Client c)`. This method throws `DaoException`.
- Client is my entity. His attributes are annotated with javax bean validations, like `@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`.

If some constraint is violated, `ClientService` receives a `ConstraintViolationException`. But `ClientService` only expects `DaoException` or any other Exception of the "dao" module. And I want to keep it that way, throwing exceptions only related directly to the task that the object does, hiding implementation details for the higher layer (in that case, the "service" module).

What I would like to do is encapsulate `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` in a `ValidationException` of my "dao" module, and declare it in the `trows` clause, alongside with `DaoException`. AND I don't want to perform the validation checks by myself (that's why I use the `@Valid` annotation)

here is the code (abstracting interfaces, injections and everything else. to make it simple)

```
package service;

class ClientService {
    insert(Client c) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            new ClientDao().insert(c);
        } catch( DaoException e) {
            throw new ServiceException(e);
        }
    }
}

package dao;

class ClientDao {
    insert(@Valid Client c) throws DaoException {
        myEntityManagerOrAnyPersistenceStrategy.insert(c);
    }
}
```

I would like to change the dao class to something like:

```
package dao;

class ClientDao {
    insert(@Valid Client c) throws DaoException, MyValidationException {
        myEntityManagerOrAnyPersistenceStrategy.insert(c);
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to do this in the way I described.

FTR, I'm using Spring Web Flow and Hibernate in this project. The dao module contains `@Repository` classes and the service module contains `@Service` classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I don't understand something, but I guess in your case validation is performed automatically by persistence provider and has nothing to do with your `@Valid` annotation.

If so, you can simply catch `ConstraintViolationException` inside your DAO method:

```
class ClientDao {
    insert(@Valid Client c) throws DaoException, MyValidationException {
        try {
            myEntityManagerOrAnyPersistenceStrategy.insert(c);
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException ex) {
            throw new MyValidationException(...);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So there is no point of this `@Valid` annotation in the `ClientDao.insert` method? It would only be valid in a controller? (like a ManagedBean or a Spring MVC or Web Flow controller, so the controller provider would perform the validation?)

Comment: @bluefoot: No, there is no point in placing it on arbitrary methods (unless you have something special in your setup that actually handles it).

Comment: catching the exception and re-throwing is the right approach. Adding @Valid to the paramter c in the insert method would imply a method level validation which is a completely different beast. Method level validation is a suggestion in the Bean Validation specification, but that's about it. Besides, to make this work you would still need some sort of interceptor framework around the 'insert' invocation which could then trigger the parameter validation.

Comment: @axtavt: what is package of the ConstraintViolationException class. I see 2 packages for the same exception class